# Ng Bootstrap Angular 6 custom style datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I would like to change design of datepicker. I'm using Angular 6, Bootstrap 4 and ngBootstrap. I want to change many things, like background color, positions of arrow etc, display days (only first letter instead 2). Is it possible? I can't find information about it in documentation, only for custom specific days. [image]

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @PatricioVargas but my code now is only datepicker from documentation, nothing change, so I fork this example from official site https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8qjxn1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html. Now I need changing css style, order elements etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this to you CSS component

```css
::ng-deep{
  .ngb-dp-arrow > button{
    position: relative !important;
    top: 5px !important; // Assumming you want to move it 5px from top.
    }
  .ngb-dp-arrow.right > button{
    position: relative !important;
    left: 5px !important; //Assuming you want to move it 5px from left.
   }
  .ngb-dp-month-name {
    //This is an example what you can modify
    background-color: blue !important;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px !important;
    letter-spacing: 0 !important;
  } 
}
```

Side note: You have to use '!important' to override default values.